# A word evoking the feeling of being "part" of a work of fiction

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, etymology, emotions

I'm seeking a word for the experience of being intensely, vividly involved in a TV show or novel.

> I have a continuous event occur when I am reading or watching tv...that I'm not exactly sure how to describe. If a show or novel gets really intense I have a habit of getting...overwhelmed by what is occurring. Like...it feels real and like I am a part of it and I get nervous and my heart rate speeds up and I feel like it's actually happening and I end up needing to take a break from what I'm doing sit and breath for awhile and remind myself that it's not real.

Is there a word for this situation?

Comment: *Immersive* ? These days technology is being developed to build "immersive" systems, (which is too mundane compared to the immersive experience of one deeply engrossed in a piece of fiction, a play, a movie or a TV show.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Kris' comment that the word you are looking for is **immersion**. To immerse means to become completely involved in an activity (Longman).

Consider **immersive theater**, which is designed to invoke just the kind of feeling you are describing.

> Many people go to the theatre to **lose themselves in** the production, to forget their everyday worries and troubles and be transported into another world. However, no kind of theatre transports an audience quite like **immersive theatre**. In immersive theatre, the audience are not merely passive bystanders. **They are part of the story**, however small their role may be, and they are in the middle of the action.

https://space.org.uk/2014/08/04/what-is-immersive-theatre/

(The example above shows that the expression **to lose oneself in** may also work in context.)

Comment: That's been suggested in comments.

Comment: Yes, but with a question mark after it, without a reference, and without mentioning "to lose onesefl in". That said, I wouldn't mention *immersion* if you'd made your comment a full-blown answer. Edit: added credit to your comment in my answer.